# Java object to simple Json response

Tags: json

I have nested java object that need to converted to simple list.I using spring boot application. For ex : My current response looks like below.
Country{
         name : US,
         zipcodes : {
                                "postalCode": "68154"
                            },
                            {
                                "postalCode": "69001"
                            }, {
                                "postalCode": "68152"
                            },
                    }
}
Since I have zipcodes class as a list in Country class and in that class I have postalcode variable json response is like above. But I want the reponse somethink like below:

Country{
         name : US,
         zipcodes : {"68154","69001","68152"}
}

Is there any configuration in json that can convert response as above with out modifying the existing classes.

Comment: how about using a jsonArray?

Comment: I am not converting java objects to json response. Spring boot is doing that for me using ResponseEntity class. I am not sure how to intercept the response before sending with spring boot.

Comment: how does it look like?